# Homestead with hhvm:true,but doesn't use hhvm?

Tags: laravel, hhvm

I have the last Vagrant+Homestead installation. Nginx+Laravel+php7
I've  addedd hhvm: true to yaml file like this

```
  - map: example.local
    to: /home/vagrant/Code/example/public
    hhvm: true
```

and issued vagrant reload. No error messages on startup.

However when I show phpinfo() on a page in example.local I still see PHP Version 7.0.8-2
It's there something else to do?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the php config in nginx block.
in /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.local, the config starting with

```
location ~ \.php$ {...
```

was clearly pointing to

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

I removed that whole part and replaced with

```
include hhvm.conf;
```

and restarted nginx